# Nodejs crypto decrypt is behaving inconsistently

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I have created generic crypt and decrypt functionality, it works fine when I provide an arbitrary string but when I attempt to pass in `sha256` hash string then crypto throws an error -- `error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`

Here is the code --

```
let crypto = require('crypto');

const secret = new Buffer('1234567890abcdef71234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef', 'hex');
const iv = new Buffer('1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef', 'hex');

const config = {
  secret: secret,
  iv: iv
};

function encrypt(data, sec, siv) {
  let dataBuffer = ((data instanceof Buffer)?data:Buffer.from(data));
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', sec, siv);
  let crypt = cipher.update(dataBuffer);
  crypt += cipher.final('hex');

  return Buffer.from(crypt, 'hex');
}

function decrypt(data, sec, siv) {
  let dataBuffer = ((data instanceof Buffer)?data:Buffer.from(data));
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', sec, siv);
  let decrypt = decipher.update(dataBuffer);
  decrypt += decipher.final();

  return Buffer.from(decrypt);
}

function main() {
  let test = 'asdfqwerty';
  let secretBytes = crypto.randomBytes(32);
  let secretHash = Buffer.from(crypto.createHmac('sha256', config.secret).update(secretBytes).digest('hex'));

  console.log('\nTesting test string\n===================');
  console.log(test);
  a = encrypt(test, config.secret, config.iv);
  console.log(decrypt(a, config.secret, config.iv).toString());

  console.log('\nTesting test string\n===================');
  console.log(secretHash);

  a = encrypt(secretHash, config.secret, config.iv);
  console.log(decrypt(a, config.secret, config.iv).toString());
}

try {
  main();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

However, the output is as follows --

```
Testing test string
===================
asdfqwerty
asdfqwerty

Testing test string
===================
<Buffer 62 36 62 62 37 39 36 65 63 36 36 36 64 32 63 61 64 34 63 61 32 32 39 66 32 35 64 38 64 30 61 39 34 66 31 39 34 38 62 33 63 66 33 38 64 37 65 62 33 39 ... >
Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
    at Decipheriv.final (crypto.js:181:26)
    at decrypt (/project/test2.js:24:23)
    at main (/project/test2.js:43:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/project/test2.js:47:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
```

I can not figure out why it works in the first test case yet fails on the second test case.

Here is a [repl.it link](https://repl.it/LPwI/1) to the code

Comment: `typeof data === 'Buffer'` will never be true. `typeof` only produces `'string'`, `'number'`, `'boolean'`, `'function'`, `'object'`, `'symbol'`, and `'undefined'`; you probably meant `Buffer.isBuffer(data)`.

Comment: You are so correct. Thanks for that, I thought I was losing my mind over something that turns out to be super basic.  I should be using `instancesof` to test not `typeof`. However, that doesn't fix the underlying issue since crypto methods should work with Buffers or strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research, I discovered that the issue stems from the expectations of the `AES-256` and the block size of the data to be encrypted.  The data to be encrypted cannot be larger than the expected block size (i.e. 16 bytes). If the block is larger then crypto will throw the `error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length` error.

When encrypting large data with `aes-256-cbc`, it is necessary to chunk the data into 16-byte or fewer blocks, encrypt each block, and then pack each of the results together with some form of a separator.

Similarly decrypting requires splitting the packed result by the separator, decrypting the each block, and then reassembling the results.